# How to cross compile with mingw on linux using Code::Blocks?

Tags: linux, c++11, mingw, cross-compiling, codeblocks

So I was using the `i586-mingw32msvc` compiler on linux to compile for windows. The Code::Blocks was configured like in [this](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Code%3a%3aBlocks_and_Cross_Compilers) site. Everything was fine until I tried to compile **C++11** code and the compiler said: `cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=c++0x"`, then I jus realized that the mingw32 compiler is too old for C++11 code.

So I installed the `mingw-w64` and in Code::Blocks in menu Settings->Compiler->Toolchain I changed `i586-mingw32msvc` to `i686-w64-mingw32`. The searching directories has been changed too.

Now when I try to compile **C++11** code I get this (Build log):

```
i686-w64-mingw32-g++ -Wall -fexceptions  -std=c++0x  -DWINVER=0x0400 -D__WIN95__ -D__GNUWIN32__ -DSTRICT -DHAVE_W32API_H -D__WXMSW__ -D__WINDOWS__   -I/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/include  -c /home/me/program/p1/main.cpp -o obj/Release/win/main.o
i686-w64-mingw32-g++ -L/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/lib  -o bin/Release/win/p1 obj/Release/win/main.o   -lstdc++ -lgcc -lodbc32 -lwsock32 -lwinspool -lwinmm -lshell32 -lcomctl32 -lctl3d32 -lodbc32 -ladvapi32 -lodbc32 -lwsock32 -lopengl32 -lglu32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid  
Output size is 107,04 KB
Process terminated with status 0 (0 minutes, 0 seconds)
0 errors, 0 warnings (0 minutes, 0 seconds)
```

and Build Messages shows only one line below:

```
||=== Build finished: 0 errors, 0 warnings (0 minutes, 0 seconds) ===|
```

like nothing was compiled. Anyone knows what happend?

Comment: I suggest adding `-v` just after `i686-w64-mingw32-g++`

Comment: what it means `-v` and where I can add this option in code blocks?

Comment: That is, compile with `i686-w64-mingw32-g++ -v` to understand what is really going on... I have no idea about what your Code Blocks is (probably some useless IDE). You can always type a compilation command inside some terminal...

Comment: [There](http://www.heypasteit.com/clip/0QFP) is all what I get with option `-v`, I don't see nothing bad. You say that c::B is useles, so what IDE do you prefer? :)

Comment: I don't use any IDE, I'm using `emacs`. Some people call it an IDE, I call it an editor.

Comment: Your `main.cpp` seems to be compiled. Maybe you could look at the preprocessed output (with `i686-w64-mingw32-g++ -v -C -E`), or use `nm` or `objdump` or whatever object file inspector you have (maybe some `i686-w64-mingw32-nm`?), to be sure that the relevant routine names are indeed present...

Comment: Thank you for your help, just wanted to be sure you will see ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem so I do self answer, maybe for someone else will be this helpful, so I just needed to add this following linker options: `-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -L` and that's all.

Answer (score 2):

```
Output size is 107,04 KB
```

So you got an executable of size 107kB. Is that nothing?

```
||=== Build finished: 0 errors, 0 warnings
```

I'd be happy in your place... Do you **want** compilation errors as a proof for the compiler having run?

Comment: Yes it is cool but the 'i586-mingw32msvc' has been creating an 1MB file and it shows 20 warnings

Comment: @Tom If you want more warnings: `-Wall`, if you want bigger files: `-g`.

Comment: done... still no warnings ;) I don't know if this is realy compiled?

Comment: If you want a warning, you could add `#warning I am here` in some of your source file.

Comment: I have used this warning and it really shows now 1 warning... ok, but something is wrong, when I compile normally with g++ it takes 2-4 seconds, but when I compile with i686-w64-mingw32-g++ it takes 0 second almost instantly. The produced file should have 1MB, but it has only 100KB, and when I try to run this program, they won't. I think the lib files are not linked, what should I do?

Comment: In general, work inside a terminal, with commands. Perhaps edit your question to show which commands did you try, and some of their results. And IIRC, `i686-w64-mingw32-g++` might use some `ccache` magic -but I am not sure of that- which would explain the nearly 0 second compilation time. Did you consider adding some debugging `printf` just after your `main`? Do you have some constructed static data? Can you use some debugger?